# Using URL parameters to place content into a div?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, url, parameters

I'm working on a opt in page. I would like the user's current subscription data to display at the top of the page. My method is placing content into a div based on URL parameters. If the parameter does not exist I want it to drop into a different div. See code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var testSub = '<span>Subscription data</span>';
        if (/testnews=1/.test(window.location.href)) {
            document.getElementById('subscribed').innerHTML = testSub;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('not_subscribed').innerHTML = testSub;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="subscribed"></div>
    <div id="not_subscribed"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Haven't tested it, but this seems to look fairly reasonable already. Can you clarify what you're stuck with?

Comment: Something in the if/else statement isn't working for me. The content isn't dropping into the div when I host it live and test the URL with the specified parameter. If I drop an alert in the if statement that works fine, so I know something has to be wrong in the if/else.

Comment: More specifically, I believe these 2 lines are incorrect:
document.getElementById('subscribed').innerHTML = testSub;
document.getElementById('not_subscribed').innerHTML = testSub;

Comment: Instead of using a regex for testing the URL query string, I'd recommend doing it right, by actually inspecting the values (for example, if testnews=11 or if othertestnews=1, yours would still pass). You can use something like [URIjs](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/) to read the query string into an object.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out. Just needed to wrap my code in an onload funtion:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     window.onload = function(){
        var testSub = '<span>Subscription data</span>';
        if (/testnews=1/.test(window.location.href)) {
            document.getElementById('subscribed').innerHTML = testSub;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('not_subscribed').innerHTML = testSub;
        }
    }
    </script>


<body>
    <div id="subscribed"></div>
    <div id="not_subscribed"></div>
</body>

</html>
```